# how to Insert date (yyyymmdd) into parametized copy statement? (postgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, date, plpgsql

Hello i have the following parameterized copy statement:

```
Do $$
Begin 
EXECUTE format(
           'COPY test FROM PROGRAM ''curl "https://example.com/events/123&start_date=%sT000000Z"''',
           '20210331'
        );
End
$$ ;
```

and i want to know how could i make the parameterized date at the end (20210331) correspond to a day before the current date, for example as of now it would be '20211905'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that string with

```
to_char(current_date - 1, 'YYYYDDMM')
```